# How to make sure if a file is downloaded successfully

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my project, I want to download file and this file will be deleted after download.

I had set async:false in first ajax to confirm that downloading file is finish.

```
 //this is download file code:
 $.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        async: false,
        data:{files:files},
        url:'oat.php',
        success:function(data){
            delFile=data.name;
            alert(delFile);
            window.location=delFile;
        }
    });

    //this is delete file code:
    $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           data:{delFile:delFile},
           url:'delFileoat.php',
           success:function(data){
            }
        });
```

But unlucky, delete is always before download as it needs time to download, but deleting file just for a second.

So I always get messages about "can not find file in server".

Is there a return value for `window.location=delFile` after downloading file successfully?

Comment: How do you output the file? Is it handled by your webserver or a php-script?

Comment: @TobiasF. by webserver

Comment: If it would run via a script you could output it via something like `readfile()` and afterwards (when the download was complete) you could go ahead and delete the file.

Comment: I need to pass a group of file's names to server, and pack these files to zip, and download it.  so i use ajax, not form. I have tried readfile() in oat.php, but It worked fail, That is why i chose  window.location

Answer (score 1):

[`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is deprecated. You can delete your file in `success` callback. like below

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    files: files
  },
  url: 'oat.php',
  success: function(data) {
    // do your stuff
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        delFile: delFile
      },
      url: 'delFileoat.php',
      success: function(data) {}
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: In my webserver

Comment: If the result is the same with this approach, the actual delete might not be the problem. Can you verify oat.php works correctly without the delete?